# How does select block wait on ctx.Done() operation?

Tags: go

In the below code:

```
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(req.Context(), 5000*time.Second)

    // Wait for the response or timeout
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Println("timeout, cancel work...")

        // Cancel the request and wait for it to complete
        // this will shutdown the go-routine immediately
        tr.CancelRequest(req)
        log.Println(<-ch)

    case err := <-ch:
        // do something
    }
```

---

`select` waits for two receive operations simultaneously. One receive operation(`<-ch`) is a block operation

Amidst execution of `select` block, Is `ctx.Done()` invoked more than once in `select` block, to verify, if `ctx.Done()` returns a channel? until `<-ch` is blocked...

Comment: Please read [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5) for simple questions of how Go works.

Comment: @Flimzy I read this, before asking query. My question is, whether `Done()` gets called, when it says: "A `select` blocks until one of its cases can run"

Comment: @Flimzy My question is, I know, `ctx.Done()` is executed, but does it exeucte more than once?

Comment: No, of course not. Why would it execute more than once?

Comment: Do you think it has to execute once "to verify, if ctx.Done() returns a channel?" ?  Obviously not. It already knows it returns a channel, because Go is strictly typed. If it didn't return a channel, it wouldn't compile, and your code would not run at all.

Comment: @Flimzy yes you are right, it should give compile error, if `ctx.Done()` does not return channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spec: Select statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)

> For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send statements **are evaluated exactly once**, in source order, upon entering the "select" statement.

`select` calls `ctx.Done()` only once. It returns a channel, and the receive operation from this channel is monitored if it can proceed.

If the `5000*time.Second` timeout expires, or if the parent context (`req.Context()`) is cancelled (e.g. times out or its `cancel()` function is called), then the channel that was returned by `ctx.Done()` will be closed, so receiving from it can proceed (it will not be a blocking operation anymore). [Spec: Receive operator:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)

> A receive operation on a [closed](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close) channel can always proceed immediately, yielding the element type's [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) after any previously sent values have been received.

Answer (score -3):

Usually, when you use a blocking channel and a timeout function, you can put it in a for-select loop.

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(req.Context(), 5000*time.Second)

    // Wait for the response or timeout
   for {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Println("timeout, cancel work...")

        // Cancel the request and wait for it to complete
        // this will shutdown the go-routine immediately
        tr.CancelRequest(req)
        log.Println(<-ch)
        break
    case err := <-ch:
        // do something
        break
    }
   }
```

In this case the `<-ch` is not blocking anymore and the select calls `ctx.Done()` more than once. If you don't use the for-loop the `ctx.Done()` is called only once (as @icza already pointed out)

Comment: "In this case the <-ch is not blocking anymore" Why?